# Is a random subset of exchangable data still exchangable? How about iid?

Tags: sampling, iid, exchangeability

I am dividing the data that I work with (iid, thus also exchangable) into training and calibration sets based on the random sampling (drawn from Bernoulli dist with parameter q).

Does this still ensure exchangability? I do not happen to find any results in the literature

Comment: Welcome to CV, Anđela.  By modeling your data as a realization of a tuple of random variables $(X_1,\ldots, X_n),$ and the corresponding Bernoulli variables (independent of the data, presumably) as $(Y_1,\ldots,Y_n),$ it appears you are asking whether the sequence $(X_j\mid Y_j=1)$ is exchangeable.  Would this be a correct interpretation?  If so, it seems that applying a definition of exchangeability makes the answer immediate.  What definition do you have in mind?